# How to write data to stdin of the first process in a Python shell pipeline?

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, posix, pipeline

I see this code snippet referenced quite a lot during discussions around Python subprocess pipelines.  Obligatory link: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline

Modified slightly:

```
p1 = subprocess.Popen(['cat'],
                      stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                      stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p2 = subprocess.Popen(['head', '-n', '1'],
                      stdin=p1.stdout,
                      stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
# Allow p1 to receive a SIGPIPE if p2 exits.
p1.stdout.close()
output = p2.communicate()[0]
```

This shell pipeline is pointless, except to succinctly demonstrate the challenge.  Input `"abc\ndef\nghi\n"` and only `"abc\n"` should be captured in `output`.

What is the best way to write data to `p1.stdin`?  I am aware of the `input` argument to `subprocess.Popen.communicate()`, but it won't work in a pipeline.  Also, the solution needs to handling blocking correctly.

My guess: Reverse engineer the code behind `communicate()` and create another version for this specific issue.  Before I do that, I want to ask if there is a simpler solution of which I am not aware.

Answer (score 0):

Write to `p1.stdin` and then close it before calling `p2.communicate()`:

```
In [1]: import subprocess

In [2]: %cpaste
Pasting code; enter '--' alone on the line to stop or use Ctrl-D.
:p1 = subprocess.Popen(['cat'],
:                      stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
:                      stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
:p2 = subprocess.Popen(['head', '-n', '1'],
:                      stdin=p1.stdout,
:                      stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
:p1.stdout.close()
:--

In [3]: p1.stdin.write(b'This is the first line.\n')
Out[3]: 24

In [4]: p1.stdin.write(b'And here is the second line.\n')
Out[4]: 29

In [5]: p1.stdin.close()

In [6]: p2.communicate()
Out[6]: (b'This is the first line.\n', None)
```

(Don't forget the newlines in the data you send to `cat`, or it won't work.)

Comment: I think your solution will block if data is very large for stdin, or process blocks stdin.  This is quite common, in my experience.

Comment: If the subprocess blocks (doesn't process) stdin, there is little you can do about it. The `write` calls should then raise `BlockingError`, which would signal you that the pipe is blocked and you should try again later.

Comment: @kevinarpe: as long as the 2nd subprocess does not begin to write before the 1st subprocess done reading; there shouldn't be any issues. Otherwise (as you've mentioned) a deadlock is possible. @ Roland Smith: nonblocking io would help here iff input and output are concurrent.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian But how does one force nonblocking io? I don't see anything in the `io` module that controls that. You can control buffering when you use `open()`, but since the pipes to a subprocess are opened for you, I don't see a way to force that.

Comment: @RolandSmith: the "how" depends on the "what do you want" e.g., you could use `fcntl` to set `O_NONBLOCK` flag for the pipe so that `.write()` would raise exceptions corresponding to `EAGAIN` or `EWOULDBLOCK` errno. Personally, I prefer solutions based on threading,asyncio,twisted,gevent,select modules if I need asynchronous I/O.

Comment: @jfs, ...most pipelines run asynchronously, excluding tools like `sort` or `shuf` that need to consume all input before they can write any output (because the first line of output can potentially changed based on the last line of input). That's for good reason: Means programs don't need to buffer content in memory, and *not* buffering allows better parallelization since all pipeline components can do their work concurrently.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I don't understand why do you address this to me? Do you think I said something to the contrary? If you look at my answers in the subprocess tag, you are likely to find  several examples of concurrent reading/writing. Even the simplest communicate() call reads/writes concurrently [2 processes case]. For 3+ processes, you could use threads/asyncio as mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call an equivalent of `p1.communicate(b"abc\ndef\nghi\n")` and `output = p2.communicate()[0]` *concurrently*. A portable way to do it is to use threads or `asyncio`.

Answer (score 0):

As a working example:

```
import subprocess, threading

# Unmodified from original code
p1 = subprocess.Popen(['cat'],
                      stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                      stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p2 = subprocess.Popen(['head', '-n', '1'],
                      stdin=p1.stdout,
                      stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

# New code: Start a thread that writes stdin, and closes it when complete
def write_stdin():
    p1.stdin.write("abc\ndef\nghi\n")
    p1.stdin.close()

write_t = threading.Thread(target = write_stdin)
write_t.start()

# Unmodified from original code
p1.stdout.close()
output = p2.communicate()[0]
```